# If $p$ is a prime satisfying $n<p<2n$ then $\binom{2n}{n}\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

We have that $\binom{2n}{n}= (2n)!/(n!)^2=k$ for some natural number $k$ as binomial coefficients are integers and in this case $k$ must be positive. Then $(n!)^2 \mid (2n)!$ but the $\gcd((n!)^2,p)) = 1$. This means that $(n!)^2 \mid ((2n)!/p)$. So $(2n)!/p = k(n!)^2$ which implies that $pk = (2n)!/(n!)^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$ and the congruence follows.

Comment: What's your question?  It's obvious that $n<p≤2n\implies p\,|\,(2n)!  \,\text {but}\, p\,\nmid\, n!$  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: The title is the question, there is only one place I found on this site for the question, and it doesn't have a full proof.

Comment: The statement and your proof totally check out.

Comment: @CadeReinberger Except that there might not be such a prime, e.g., for $n=1$.

Comment: It is by assumption that such a $p$ exists.

Comment: But that's OK, because it's an if-then statement: *if* there's a prime, then ...

Comment: The assumption might be nonsense, so that the congruence then also is empty.

Comment: Yes...in which case the implication is true, which is what needs to be shown.

Comment: Sure, I know. Nevertheless it is interesting to ask when this assumption makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That proof looks fine to me.

You write
$$
(n!)^2 \mid ((2n)!/p)
$$
but you probably need to first explain by the right hand side is an integer. (It clearly IS, because $p$ is one of the factors in $(2n)!$, but you should probably SAY so.)

Comment: I was going to but a figured if I did I also would have to put why the above gcd is $1$. I just tend to like to leave out these redudancies if the hypothesis and its assumptions are simple enough.